# Convert JSON Array to Sequence of JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON Array String

```
[
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true }
]
```

I want to convert JSON Array String to Sequence of JSON Objects string
like

```
{"ok":true}
{"ok":true}
{"ok":true}
{"ok":true}
{"ok":true}
```

I used `jsonarraystring.replace(/,{/g , "\n{")` but it is not safe.

Is there any library in javascript to handle this?

Comment: Won't JSON.stringify() do the work?

Comment: `JSON.stringify('[{ok:true},{ok:true}]')`  gives the result `"[{ok:true},{ok:true}]"`

Comment: Expected result will be `"[{ok:true} {ok:true}]"`

Comment: After JSON.stringify(), replace comma with whitespace?

Comment: What is a "JSON Array String"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true },
    { "ok": true }
].map(JSON.stringify).join("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Shanimal's answer is correct.

You can test the code, by this way:

```js
(function() {
  var jsonarraystring =
  [
      { "ok": true },
      { "ok": true },
      { "ok": true },
      { "ok": true },
      { "ok": true }
  ];


  console.log(jsonarraystring.map(JSON.stringify).join("\n"));

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for other options you can use **$.parseJSON()**

```
function () {
      var str = '[{ "ok": true },{ "ok": false },{ "ok": true }]';

      var jsonObjArray = $.parseJSON(str);

      for(var i=0;i<jsonObjArray.length;i++){
          alert(jsonObjArray[i]["ok"]);
      }            
}
```